# Properties of Enum DatabaseLogType

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Where can I find the properties of the BaseEnum `DatabaseLogType` in AX?
It is used in (`Sys`)`DatabaseLog`?

I know there is a [MSDN-Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa576390%28v=ax.50%29.aspx), but is there any way to get those properties in AX itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the AOT and browse to Data Dictionary -> Base Enums.

Expand the type, and the element are listed.

You can then view the element properties.

**Edit:** This doesn't work for DatabaseLogType as it is a System Enum and not a Base Enum. I will leave the answer for future reference when people are searching for Base Enums

**Edit 2: Work around for system enums!**

As system Enums cannot be viewed in the AOT you can use the following job to view them (works on any Enum);

```
static void DisplaySystemEnum(Args _args)
{
    DictEnum dblt;
    int i;
    ;

    dblt = new DictEnum(enumName2Id("DatabaseLogType"));

    for (i=0; i < dblt.values(); i++)
    {
        info(strfmt("Value:%1 Name:%2 Label:%3",
                     int2str(dblt.index2Value(i)), 
                     dblt.index2Name(i),
                     dblt.index2Label(i)));
    }
}
```

Also take a look at [MSDN DictEnum Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa864605%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) to see what else you could do to customise the job for your own needs.

Comment: That's not correct. DatabaseLogType seems to be a System-BE or something else. Anyway, it can **not** be found in AOT/BaseEnums, like it can be handled in common. That's the reason, I asked ;)

Comment: @Nico i think i have a workaround, but i want to try it in ax tomorrow before posting!

Comment: Would be nice to hear about your results!